# Cannot save instance state for recyclerview in fragment when orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate

I'm having trouble getting my recyclerview to save state on orientation change. Have used onSaveInstanceState in my fragment but obviously not correctly as it is not working. Any advice and pointers on how to fix?

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private boolean mTwoPane;
ArrayList<Recipe> myList;
List<Steps> steps;
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
StepsFragment fragment;

//Eventbus
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_two);


    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    myList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
    String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("intent");
    int result = Integer.parseInt(id);
    steps = (ArrayList) myList.get(result - 1).getSteps();

    String nameString = myList.get(result - 1).getName();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(nameString);


    if (findViewById(R.id.android_me_linear_layout) != null) {

        mTwoPane = true;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();


            arguments.putParcelableArrayList("myList", myList);
            arguments.putInt("result", result);
            arguments.putBoolean("twoPane", mTwoPane);

            StepsFragment fragment = new StepsFragment();

            fragment.setArguments(arguments);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();


        }



    } else {
        // We're in single-pane mode and displaying fragments on a phone in separate activities
        mTwoPane = false;

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();


        arguments.putParcelableArrayList("myList", myList);
        arguments.putInt("result", result);
        arguments.putBoolean("twoPane", mTwoPane);

        StepsFragment fragment = new StepsFragment();

        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();



    }


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(mTwoPane) {


        startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessage(Message event) {

    if (event.getMessage() == 2) {


        Fragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();

        newFragment.setArguments(event.getBundle());

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);


        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Eventbus worked");


    }

    else if ( event.getMessage() == 3){

        Fragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();

        newFragment.setArguments(event.getBundle());

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();



    }


}

}
```

StepsFragment

```
public class StepsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {



ArrayList<Recipe> myList;
List<Steps> myStepsList;
List <Ingredients> ingredients;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter stepItemRecyclerViewAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

int result;
List<String> ingredientsString;
String string;
Boolean mTwoPane;
Parcelable listState;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("myArrayListTwo",(ArrayList) myStepsList);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if(savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("myArrayListTwo")){
        myStepsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    else{
        myStepsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("myArrayListTwo");
    }


    mTwoPane = getArguments().getBoolean("twoPane");
    myList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("myList");
    result = getArguments().getInt("result") - 1;
    myStepsList = myList.get(result).getSteps();
    ingredients = myList.get(result).getIngredients();


    //Create a String array for all ingredients strings
    ingredientsString = new ArrayList<>();
    ingredientsString.add("Ingredients" + "\n");

    for(int x = 0; x < ingredients.size(); x++){

        ingredientsString.add(ingredients.get(x).getIngredient() + " " + ingredients.get(x).getQuantity() + " " + ingredients.get(x).getMeasure());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, ingredientsString.get(x).toString());
    }



    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : ingredientsString){
        stringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
    }

    string = stringBuilder.toString();



}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_steps, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        stepItemRecyclerViewAdapter = new StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter(myStepsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(stepItemRecyclerViewAdapter);


        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(string);


    return rootView;
}


public class StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final List<Steps> mValues;



    public StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Steps> items) {

        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
        return new StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final StepItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);


        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getShortDescription());




        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(mTwoPane){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();

                    args.putParcelableArrayList("myList", myList);
                    args.putInt("result", result);
                    args.putString("int", holder.mItem.getId());
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Message(2, args));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "You clicked a button" + holder.mItem.toString());



                } else if( mTwoPane == false){

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();

                    args.putParcelableArrayList("myList", myList);
                    args.putInt("result", result);
                    args.putString("int", holder.mItem.getId());
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Message(3, args));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "You clicked a button" + holder.mItem.toString());

                }


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public  View mView;
        public TextView mContentView;
        public Steps mItem;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}













}
```

activity_main_two.xml
https://github.com/RJRogers/TwoPaneUITest/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main_two.xml

fragment_steps.xml
https://github.com/RJRogers/TwoPaneUITest/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_steps.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that jumps out at me from your posted code is this (in your activity):

> ```
> if (findViewById(R.id.android_me_linear_layout) != null) {
>     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>         ...
>         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
>                                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
>                                    .commit();
>     }
> }
> else {
>     ...
>     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
>                                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
>                                .commit();
> }
> ```

In general, you should only have to add the fragment once, when `savedInstanceState` is null, regardless of orientation. The fragment manager will automatically save and restore your fragment even when your activity's layout changes (as long as both layouts have a container with the same id). It is possible that this is causing a new fragment to appear, instead of one that has had its state saved and restored.

Another thing that stands out is this (in your fragment):

> ```
> if(savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("myArrayListTwo")){
>     myStepsList = new ArrayList<>();
> }
> else{
>     myStepsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("myArrayListTwo");
> }
> ...
> myStepsList = myList.get(result).getSteps();
> ```

This looks like you're accidentally overwriting the saved list with a new one based on the fragment's arguments bundle. I can't exactly follow precisely what this fragment/activity are trying to do, but this seems like a plausible spot for your problem to be hiding.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!!! Fixing the issue you pointed out with savedInstanceState in my fragment worked. @Ben P.

Answer (score -2):

You can add this line inside the activity in your Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: This is an antipattern that should stop being spread. The framework destroying and recreating your activities on orientation change is something everyone should just learn how to handle.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work the way I need it to given I want to change layouts on rotation.